# Assigning worker names to groups based on the number of days they've worked

Tags: python, text-files

This will be hard to explain but please bare with me. I'm currently trying to complete a question for an online course and I have literally no idea what to do. The scenario of the question places me as a programmer in an office that needs to create a program assigning specific staff members that have attended a conference. The task gave me two text files; **one text file titled** *"confPack.txt"* **that reads**

Basic conference pack
Bonus conference pack

**And another titled** *"employees.txt"* **that reads:**

> Williams,Mary,Y
>
> Nguyen,Vinh,,Y
>
> Kingsley,Margret
>
> Kline,Bob,Y,Y
>
> Mitchell,Frank,Y
>
> Lowe,Elizabeth,Y,Y

Basically, I need to assign certain staff members to their appropriate group/"pack" based on how many days they have attended the conference. The "Y"'s in the employee.txt file  represents the amount of days they have attend (one Y = one  day of attendance).

The course question itself wants me to access the confpack.txt file and read the records into an array  , access the employees.txt file and loop through the records (checking for the end of file) and use logical operators to select the appropriate conference attendees. They said it should be displayed like so:

> Report date: [dd/mm/yyyy] *i've already displayed the time correctly
>
> Attendee: [Surname, first name] Pack/s: [1 or 2 days pack], [both days pack]

And here is what my code looks like so far:

```
import datetime


dTime = datetime.datetime.now()


confFile = open("confPack.txt", "r+")

print("Report Date: "+ dTime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

print(confFile.read())

with open("employees.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    for line in data:
        words = line.split(",")
        print(words)

confFile.close()
```

Any help is appreciated. And if you're wondering why I can't contact my course teachers for help, believe me when I say that they are never online.

**Edit:** In regards @Adirio
I want the output to look like this:

Report Date: 7/9/2020

```
Attendee: [Williams, Mary] Pack/s: [Basic Conference Pack]
Attendee: [Nguyen, Vinh] Pack/s: [Basic Conference Pack]
Attendee: [Kingsley, Margret] Pack/s: [N/A]
Attendee: [Kline, Bob] Pack/s: [Bonus Conference Pack]
Attendee: [Mitchell, Frank] Pack/s: [Basic Conference Pack]
Attendee: [Lowe, Elizabeth] Pack/s: [Bonus Conference Pack]
```

**Edit #2:** Thanks again @Adirio for the answer. However, I actually needed to access the confPack.txt file which reads:

> Basic Conference Pack
>
> Bonus Conference Pack

and the print out either the Basic or Bonus conference Pack for its employee.

```
    from datetime import datetime


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, surname, name, *args):
        self.name = name.strip()
        self.surname = surname.strip()
        self.days = 0
        for arg in args:
            if arg.strip() == 'Y':
                self.days += 1


now = datetime.now()
print("Report Date: " + now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))


#Here i've tried making a .readlines variable to print out the specific conference pack
conf = open("confPack.txt")
all_lines  = conf.readlines()

with open("employees.txt", "r") as f:
    employees = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if len(line.strip()) != 0:
            employees.append(Employee(*line.split(",")))

for employee in employees:
    print(f'Attendee: [{employee.surname}, {employee.name}]', end=' ')
    if employee.days == 2:
        print("Pack/s: [" + all_lines[2]+"]") 
    elif employee.days == 1:
        print("Pack/s: [" + all_lines[0]+"]")
    else:
        print("Pack/s: [N/A]")
```

Output:

```
Report Date: 09/09/2020
Attendee: [Williams, Mary] Pack/s: [Basic conference pack
]                #As you can see, it prints on a new line
Attendee: [Nguyen, Vinh] Pack/s: [Basic conference pack
]
Attendee: [Kingsley, Margret] Pack/s: [N/A]
Attendee: [Kline, Bob] Pack/s: [Bonus conference pack]
Attendee: [Mitchell, Frank] Pack/s: [Basic conference pack
]
Attendee: [Lowe, Elizabeth] Pack/s: [Bonus conference pack]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: post your expected output and also post the data of `confPack.txt`

Comment: In your provided code, you are opening the employee.txt file twice, one without doing anything to it.

Comment: @deadshot Ok, i've placed it above the code

Comment: it's still not clear don't post generic output post the output you are expecting for the data you posted

Comment: @Adirio Sorry, Ive added what I want the output to look like

Comment: @jh_135 Edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will clean your original code a bit, removing the file you are opening and closing for nothing and using the a `with` clause for the other as it is a very healthy pattern.

```py
from datetime import datetime


now = datetime.now()
print("Report Date: " + now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

with open("confPack.txt", "r+") as confFile:
    print(confFile.read())

with open("employees.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = line.split(",")
        print(words)
```

Now let's get to work. We will create a class that represents each employee:

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, surname, name, *args):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.days = 0
        for arg in args:
            if arg.strip() == 'Y':
                self.days += 1
```

The `__init__` method accepts the arguments as they are read from the file (surname, name, and a sequence of 'Y'). The name and surname are assigned directly while the rest of the arguments are stored in a list called `args`. We loop through this list adding 1 day to the day counter if it is equal to 'Y'. The `.strip()` part removes leading and trailing whitespaces so that we can compare to 'Y' safely.

So all together:

```py
from datetime import datetime


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, surname, name, *args):
        self.name = name.strip()
        self.surname = surname.strip()
        self.days = 0
        for arg in args:
            if arg.strip() == 'Y':
                self.days += 1


print("Report Date: " + datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

with open("confPack.txt", "r+") as f:
    packs = ['N/A']
    for line in f.readlines():
        if len(line.strip()) != 0:
            packs.append(line.strip())

with open("employees.txt", "r") as f:
    employees = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if len(line.strip()) != 0:
            employees.append(Employee(*line.split(",")))

# Do whatever you need with the employee list
for employee in employees:
    print(f"Attendee: [{employee.surname}, {employee.name}] Pack/s: [{packs[employee.days]}]")
```

We could also make the part where we open the files shorter by using list comprehensions:

```py
with open("confPack.txt", "r+") as f:
    packs = ['N/A'] + [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip())]

with open("employees.txt", "r") as f:
    employees = [Employee(line.split(",")) for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip())]
```

Comment: Apologies, but I'm getting  TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'. What do I need to add? Sorry if the answer is obvious

Comment: Do you have any empty line? Or any line with only the Surname?

Comment: I haven't added anything new to what you have given me. It appears to have a problem in the 23rd line:  "employees.append(Employee(line.split(",")))"

Comment: I mean in the employees.txt file

Comment: I haven't made any changes to that as well

Comment: My question is not if you made any changes, my question is if there are empty lines in that file. Because fro empty lines, `line` would be `''`, and then splitting by `","` would return `['']` which will try to convert into an employee with `''` as the surname and nothing else, thus giving you the error that you are not providing a name. Try the edited code that added a check for that kind of empty lines.

Comment: No, I don't think there are any free lines. I've displayed exactly what was in the file in my original comment

Comment: Have you tried the edited code? I made a check that should handle those cases. Probably the last line of the file is empty, so I just omit empty lines.

Comment: Yeah I have. Even tried copy and pasting it in and it still gets that name error, weird.

Comment: I was missing a `*` sorry, try it now. It is in the line you mentioned earlier (23rd). (Also added the `N/A` message for those that don't have 1 or 2 days)

Comment: Ah there we go it works now. Just one small issue, the name "Kingsly, Margret" who has no Y at the end isnt exactly displaying correctly. You can see it here: https://imgur.com/a/w2nKuW1

Comment: @jh_135 the issue is that as it has no `Y` the name is taking the trailing `\n` character. I edited my answer to remove leading and trailing backspaces for name and surname. That should fix it.

Comment: Wow. You're the most helpful person i've seen on this site. Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: I'm sorry for budging again, but it turns out I have to access the "confPack.txt" file, and then print out either the Basic or Bonus conference pack for each employee. Here I tried opening the confPack.txt file and then I tried printing out the line I needed: https://imgur.com/a/O76OeZw

Comment: @jh_135 either make another question linking here and mentioning me in the comments or edit this question to add the new requirements if they are related but do not post code as images please as we can't copy paste from them. Also include which are the contents of the confPack.txt file.

Comment: @jh_135 I made an edit to adapt to the new requirements. The file reading part is very similar to the other file, with the exception that we have an item already for 0 days: "N/A".  For the output I just moved everything into a single print statement with the `f"..."` string notation that allow us to format it with python code between curly brackets (`{}`)

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks again. Sorry for being a pain, i'm still quite new to programming